# How to add a new column in a migration file

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Ruby on rails and Sqlite and I got the `rspec` and `factorybot` gems. And i'm on Linux ubuntu.

Migration

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :description
      t.integer :price
      t.string :picture
      t.string :author

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_02_07_071425) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "description"
    t.integer "price"
    t.string "picture"
    t.string "author"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

end
```

article.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :article do
    title { Faker::Company.name }
    description { Faker::Lorem.paragraph(sentence_count: 35)}
    price { Faker::Number.decimal(l_digits: 2) }
    picture { Faker::Company.logo }
    author { Faker::FunnyName.two_word_name }
  end
end
```

I just want add a new row like `counter` 0, but I tried everything (db:migrate, reset, modify all files..) every time my counter is undefined.

What do I need to do?

Comment: What EXACTLY are you trying to do? What do you mean by by `ligne` (english please)? Are you aware that your test examples run in a database transaction and the changes are rolled back after each example?

Comment: I'm guessing that's a typo for `line`

Comment: Try: `rails g migration addCounterToArticles counter:integer; rails db:migrate`

Comment: O yes is created a new migrate and if i db:migrate is added on my Article but not the same files.  But it's work fine

Thanks a lot !

Comment: If you want to use the same file: `rake db:drop && rake db:create && rake db:migrate`